# c# EF WCF DataService Override SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, wcf-data-services, dbcontext

I have an c# solution that has the following projects:

- Application
- Model
- DataContext
- DataService

DataContext project is where I configure my DBContext with all the DbSet's, etc.
I have my ApplicationContext.cs with the following:

```
public class ApplicationContext: DbContext
    {

        public ApplicationContext(): base("DefaultDB")
        {

        }
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

        }
public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("User ID must be provided");
        }
public int SaveChanges(int userId)
        {
            // Get all Added/Deleted/Modified entities (not Unmodified or Detached)
            foreach (var ent in this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(p => p.State == System.Data.EntityState.Added || p.State == System.Data.EntityState.Deleted || p.State == System.Data.EntityState.Modified))
            {
                // For each changed record, get the audit record entries and add them
                foreach (AuditLog x in GetAuditRecordsForChange(ent, userId))
                {
                    this.AuditLogs.Add(x);
                }
            }
.........
}
```

Here I'm overriding the **SaveChanges()** method in order to receive the **userId** that is performing the action and then save that into an auditlog.

This is working great if I don't user **DataServices**.

Now, I have my DataService project with the following .svc:

```
public class Security : DataService<ApplicationContext>
    {
        // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
            // Examples:
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("SecurityUsers", EntitySetRights.All);
            // config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("MyServiceOperation", ServiceOperationRights.All);
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;

            // Other configuration here...
            config.UseVerboseErrors = true; // TODO - Remove for production?
        }

    }
```

Then, in my Application project (start up project) I added a service reference to the DataService just created.

Everything seems working fine except that the method **SaveChanges()** don't have the option for the **int value** (**userId**). It seems that the override I created is not reflected when adding the service reference.

Any clue on how to solve it or a workaround to deal with it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of your problem is that you have broken Liskov's Substitution Principle. The solution is to return to a model where you adhere to Liskov's Substitution Principle. Firstly. Remove your `public int SaveChanges(int userId)` and place all the code into the original `public override int SaveChanges()`. This will break your code.

Then find a method to inject the userId to your method. Since EF is meant to be short lived, I would suggest you can use the constructor to inject to a field.

The more architecturally sound idea however, would be to use the `Identity` classes. This will tie the EF class to the authentication framework you are using. Consider using `Thread.CurrentPrinciple.Identity` inside `public override int SaveChanges()`.

Comment: So, what you tell me is to override just the SaveChanges() method and inside it figure out a way to get the current user that is logged into the application?... sound reasonable! thanks a lot

Comment: Basic jist of it, mixed in with some core OOP concepts.